# Rust - запись файла в исходном формате, как понять формат?

Tags: rust

Есть файл, данные из которого читаются вот так:

```
let mut file = std::fs::File::open("test.img").expect("Unable to open file");
    
  const READ_MAX_LEN: usize = 7;
    
let mut bin = [0; READ_MAX_LEN];
    
let bytes_read = handle.take(READ_MAX_LEN as u64).read(&mut bin)?;
    
let _str_src = bin[..bytes_read].iter().map(|byte|format!("{byte:02x?}")).collect::<String>();
```

Как в таком же виде добавить в него данные? Если я не ошибаюсь файл читается по 7 байт, затем каждый байт преобразуется в строку и склеивается вместе. Как реализовать обратную операцию?

Я начал делать (через крейт hex = "0.4.3"), но не уверен, что правильно сделал.

```
    fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = fs::OpenOptions::new().create(true).append(true).open("test.img")?;
    
    let dates: [&str; 2] = ["03011703122220", "03011303122220"];
    

    for dat in &dates {
        let decoded = hex::decode(dat).expect("Decoding failed");
        let _remaining = file.write(&decoded);
           println!("{:?}", decoded);
        let hex_string = hex::encode(&decoded);
           println!("{}", hex_string);  
    }
    Ok(())

}
```

Comment: *"не уверен, что правильно сделал"* - сравните выхлоп программы с ожидаемым, сообщите о результатах.